# Magento layered navigation attribute issue

Tags: magento

Somehow the color attribute BLACK is showing up in my layered navigation options even though the category does not feature any items with the mentioned color. I've noticed this happens in all of my store (Magento 1.5.10) categories and ONLY with configurable products.

Someone got an idea how I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reindex indexes if you didn't yet. Start with `Product Attributes`

Comment: Thank you Zifus - tried to re-index all data, clear cache although no result.

Comment: another guess: do you have filtrable (with results) for the color attribute set?

Comment: Hi zifus - yes I have enabled it

Comment: Sorry no other ideas. Maybe perhaps one of your simple products have that color. Are simples visible individually?

Comment: There was a glitch in an extension - it got fixed. Thanks for your help though @ Zifus

Comment: No problem! Feel free to post answer outlining extension name

Comment: the extension I've used was CJM color swatches pro